# How to find objects created within given date range?

Tags: python, django, python-2.7

I have a model:

```
class Customer(models.Model):
    Name = models.TextField(blank=False)
    Surname = models.TextField(blank=False)
    PhoneNumber = models.TextField()
    Address = models.TextField()
    SendSms = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    SendEmail = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    Email = models.TextField()
    Created = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)

    @classmethod
    def create(cls, name, surname, phoneNumber, address , sendSms, sendEmail, email):
        customer = cls(Name=name, Surname=surname, PhoneNumber=phoneNumber
                        , Address=address, SendSms=sendSms, SendEmail=sendEmail
                        , Email=email)
        customer.save()
        return customer
```

In a view, i want to find Customers created within given date range. Let's say 7 days.

Below code:

```
def RecentCustomers(request):
    return render_to_response("Customer/AllCustomers.html", {
        "customers": Customer.objects.filter(
            date__range=[datetime.date.today() - datetime.timedelta(days=7), datetime.date.today()])})
```

Gives:

> Cannot resolve keyword 'date' into field. Choices are: Address,
>   Created, Email, Name, PhoneNumber, SendEmail, SendSms, Surname, id,
>   pet

Error. I have also tried:

```
def RecentCustomers(request):
    return render_to_response("Customer/AllCustomers.html", {
        "customers": Customer.objects.filter(Created >= datetime.date.today() - datetime.timedelta(days=7)})
```

But that gives:

> invalid syntax

Error. How to i filter date for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Customer.objects.filter(Created__gte=datetime.date.today() - datetime.timedelta(days=7))
```

By the way, it is a good practice to create your model fields, template names, directories, functions etc. always with `lowercase` names.

---

```
from django.shortcuts import render

def recent_customers(request):
    customers = Customer.objects.filter(created__gte=datetime.date.today() - datetime.timedelta(days=7))
    return render(request, "customer/all_customers.html", {"customers": customers})
```

You might want to take a look at the [style guide](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) regarding naming convention rules in Python.